# How to configure jdbc jndi datasource in weblogic?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, datasource, jndi, weblogic12c

I am setting up my existing tomcat based multi module application to work with WEBLOGIC12c.

This application got deployed properly on weblogic but it is not connecting with my existing databases and giving below error -

```
ERROR [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' [DbUtil]: An exception occurred while sql lite database connection 
javax.naming.LinkException:  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jdbc.myDB' didn't find subcontext 'jdbc'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jdbc/myDB']; Link Remaining Name: 'jdbc/myDB'
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLNamingManager.getObjectInstance(WLNamingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.resolveObject(BasicNamingNode.java:1037)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.resolveObject(ApplicationNamingNode.java:186)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.resolveObject(BasicNamingNode.java:1009)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:223)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:132)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.lookup(BasicNamingNode.java:228)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.ApplicationNamingNode.lookup(ApplicationNamingNode.java:132)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.lookup(WLEventContextImpl.java:307)
    at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:435)
```

As I am new to Weblogic and upon some investigation I come to know that the existing context.xml is not going to bind with weblogic.

**So how can this be done for weblogic if i want to retain everything as it was working with tomcat/context.xml**

Existing context.xml has multiple databases with connection pooling configuration like this -

```
<Context>
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/devDB1"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="5"
        maxWait="-1"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=devDB1"
        username="sa"
        password="pwd1"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
        logAbandoned="false"
    />
    <Resource
        name="jdbc/devDB2"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        maxActive="100"
        maxIdle="5"
        maxWait="-1"
        driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=devDB2"
        username="sa"
        password="pwd2"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="300"
        logAbandoned="false"
           />
           ...........
```

**I expect the same configuration to be worked with weblogic jdbc resource configuration**
And also need the best possible way to achieve this for production environment.

Comment: Are you using weblogic multi tenancy? JDBC configuration is different for a multi tenancy server. This article may be helpful https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/JDBCP/programming.htm#JDBCP118

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's documentation about datasource configuration is [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/04-ConfigDataSource/configds.htm).

For all your environments create and use a WLST script to avoid manual configuration steps.